# Can't install "jenssegers/mongodb" to my project

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, lumen

I'm cloned my project from git repository and tried to install packages (composer install), but I get an error:

```
Problem 1
- jenssegers/mongodb v3.5.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.0-alpha1, 1.0.0-beta1, 1.0.0-beta2, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.0-alpha1, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.2.0-alpha1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.x-dev, v1.0.x-dev, v1.1.x-dev, v1.2.x-dev, v1.3.x-dev, v1.4.x-dev].
- mongodb/mongodb v1.4.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
```

...

```
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
- /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
- /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini


You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

> I added "extension=mongo.so" to "php.ini", but it didn't help. What I need to do for fix this?

*MacOS Mojave, Homebrew, Valet, php@7.3, lumen@5.6*

Comment: The PHP docs recommend doing `pecl install mongodb`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.homebrew.php

Comment: Did you restart the webserver once you modified the `php.ini`?

Comment: Thanks for your answers, guys. `sudo pecl install mongodb` resolved issue.

Answer (score 0):

try install mongodb lib from php

> sudo apt-get install php-mongodb

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in macOS there is no apt-get (this is linux installer), i tried run "sudo pecl install mongodb" and get an error:
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in System.php on line 294
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.6/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294

Warning: mkdir(): File exists in /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.6/share/php/pear/System.php on line 294
ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.6/pecl/20180731

Comment: you run as sudo ?

Comment: Yes, "sudo pecl install mongodb"

Comment: this error is similar to this one (https://javorszky.co.uk/2018/05/03/getting-xdebug-working-on-php-7-2-and-homebrew/?source=post_page---------------------------)
try "sudo /usr/local/lib/php/pecl install mongodb"
or try to remove the link in "/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.6/"

Comment: Result for first command: `sudo: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl: command not found`
Result for second command: `-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.3.6/: No such file or directory`